# Too many re-renders with React Hooks and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lodash

I have a component that displays a list of Cards.  I'm trying to sort the table rows but running into some issues.  When i go to the page i'm getting the following error:

**Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

and it's pointing to this line

```
setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
```

here's my full component code.  can anyone see a problem with what I'm trying to do?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
import TimeAgo from "react-timeago";
import { useSelector, useDispatch, connect } from "react-redux";
import { Table } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { searchChange } from "../reducers/searchReducer";
import _ from "lodash";
// import { useField } from "../hooks";

const searchCards = ({ baseball, search }) => {
  return search
    ? baseball.filter(a =>
        a.title[0].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    : baseball;
};

const Cards = props => {
  const [column, setColumn] = useState(null);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setData] = useState(props.cardsToShow);

  const handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setColumn(clickedColumn);
      setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, [clickedColumn]));
      setDirection("ascending");
      return;
    }

    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
    direction === "ascending"
      ? setDirection("descending")
      : setDirection("ascending");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Search />
        <h3>Vintage Card Search</h3>
        <Table sortable celled fixed striped>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "title" ? direction : null}
                onClick={handleSort("title")}
              >
                Card Title
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell># Bids</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Watchers</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Price</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Time Left</Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {props.cardsToShow.map(card => (
              <>
                <Table.Row key={card.id}>
                  <Table.Cell>{card.title}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    {card.sellingStatus[0].bidCount
                      ? card.sellingStatus[0].bidCount
                      : 0}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    {card.listingInfo[0].watchCount
                      ? card.listingInfo[0].watchCount
                      : 0}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    $
                    {card.sellingStatus &&
                      card.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]["__value__"]}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    <TimeAgo
                      date={new Date(
                        card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].endTime
                      ).toLocaleDateString()}
                    />
                  </Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
              </>
            ))}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    baseball: state.baseball,
    search: state.search,
    cardsToShow: searchCards(state)
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  searchChange
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cards);
// export default Cards;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```js
onClick={handleSort("title")}
```

by

```js
onClick={() => handleSort("title")}
```

EDIT: Reinis has written a nice explanation below!

Answer (score 5):

Yachaka has already pointed out the incorrect line, but their answer doesn't explain what the issue is.

When you pass props in React with `prop={expression}`, the expression in the brackets gets evaluated, much like function arguments are evaluated when they are passed. Hence, whenever the component is rendered, `handleSort("title")` is called. This function then causes the props to be updated, and the component is re-rendered, causing the cycle to repeat indefinitely.

So the problem is that, instead of passing a function that should be called when the button is clicked, you call that function (with `handleSort("title")`), which results in `undefined`, and causes a feedback loop.

Instead you should use an expression that returns a function. The most concise way of doing that in JavaScript is an arrow function, as Yachaka mentioned `() => handleSort("title")`. This evaluates to a function that calls `handleSort`.

Comment: thank you for this super helpful explanation.  i'm glad you wrote this, because I was a little unsure of the reason why